# What is good practice when initializing variables which will be set inside a loop?

Tags: java, loops, variables

The following code is just an example, but I find myself in this situation often where I get this error.

In this case, when I try to call isPrime(factor1) I get an error saying "variable factor1 might not have been initialized".

I understand that a quick fix would be to initialize both factor1 and factor2 to 0 or -1. But what is the best practice for situations like these?

Also note this is only a snipet of code.

```
int factor1;
int factor2;

for(int i = 2; i< n; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0){
        factor1 = n / i;
        factor2 = i;
        break;
    }
}

if(isPrime(factor1)){
    factors.add(factor1);
} else {
    factors.addAll(primeFactorization(factor1));
}
```

Comment: Usually best to initialize to whatever is the best default or initial value, but having said that, there is no one-size-fits-all, and it all depends on the situation at hand.

Comment: Side recommendation: when editing your question, click on the `?` in the upper right of the edit view to get tips and help on formatting your code in your question. Also check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more on formatting your question properly. Also, only post code that you've well-formatted before hand, including proper indentation, and avoiding over-use of blank lines. More than one blank line in a row is too many.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! The blank lines were not intentional. When I tried to get rid of them, the website told me my code was not properly formatted. Very confused but hoping to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hovercraft Full Of Eels pointed out, in most situations, you just initialize variables to some default value, for example:

```
int factor1 = 0, factor2 = 0;
for(int i = 2; i< n; i++) {
    if(n % i == 0){
        factor1 = n / i;
        factor2 = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(isPrime(factor1)){
    factors.add(factor1);
} else {
    factors.addAll(primeFactorization(factor1));
}
```